# Last 3 months of this year in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, date

I am using python to read an excel file. 
The excel file contains a 'Date' column.
My question is how to check in python if the date in the excel sheet is in the last 3 months of this year.

Excel sheet:

```
Date
2018-01-20
2018-10-01
2018-10-01
2018-11-01
2018-11-17
```

and my code is something like:

```
for i in content:
    valuerContent = content[(content['valuer'] == 'ahmad') & (content['Date'] == ??)]
```

What should I write instead of '??' to get the needed results

Comment: Can you copy your code and the data into the question instead of linking to a photo?

Comment: Not an answer because I am a complete novice at python, but I think the calendar function would help out: https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html

Comment: @RockyLi That won't work, and if you'd like to answer the question, please do so in an answer. I'd also encourage you to wait until the OP has [edit]ed his question as requested by Nick Vitha.

Comment: You could try the `datetime` module?

Comment: Presumably you would extract the month and see if it is 10, 11 or 12, or even more simply, greater than 9 since it would be unlikely to exceed 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming content['Date'] is a string

```
 valuerContent = content[(content['valuer'] == 'ahmad') and int(content['Date'].split('-')[1]) >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Only been coding in python for 4 months, but from the looks of it you could use the `datetime` module.  Here are some examples

```
import datetime as dt

check_date = (2018,11,01)

current_date = (2018,12,31)  #assuming you want to check the year 2018

if (current_date[1] - check_date[1]) < 3:
    #insert code
```

`datetime` allows you to access the month/day/year by tuple indexes.  Where [0] is year, [1] is month, [2] is day and so on.

Comment: That's interesting. I've always done it like `check_date = dt.date(year=2018, month=11, day=1)`;`print(check_date.month)`. I'd argue that my method is more readable, but seems like more typing when declaring `check_date` perhaps.